# java script How to loop though a list of href's

Tags: javascript, loops, href

i have branch of links placed one after the other with 
 between them 
i want to loop though each link and invoke its click() event 
what is the best way to do this?

```
<div id="playlistContainer" >
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadNewVideo('xxxx1','0');">Blah 1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadNewVideo('xxxxx3','0');">Blah 1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadNewVideo('xxxxx4','0');">TBlah 2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadNewVideo('xxxxx5','0');">Blah 3</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadNewVideo('xxxxx6','0');">Blah 4</a><br>
</div>
```

so when i know the first link object how can i know the next link (href object ) which is next in the list?

**UPDATE:**
Thank for answering about the loop , but my last question is , if i have the first link as object in function , how can i know what is the next link ?

Comment: You should not use HTML anchors to invoke a JavaScript action unless you are providing a valid URL—you should use something like a `<button>` instead, styled like a link if you like—and you should not place your JavaScript code directly in your HTML markup, but should instead attach your handlers to your HTML code through JavaScript (e.g. `addEventListener`).

Comment: your saying `if i have "the first link as object in function" how can i know what is the next link`, i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<as.length; i++) {
  // Call the "onclick" handler for each "a" element.
  as[i].onclick();
}
```