# Loop for creating hrefs from strings in javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, loops, popup

I am trying to dynamically create `href` links within Mapbox popups.  When hovering over a location, I am returned an array, for example:

```
"Feature","properties":{"field_1":71,"city":"Gothenburg",
"course1":"EMM-Nano","course2":"EMHRPP","course3"
:"MFAMILY","course4":"NA","course5":"NA","course6":"NA",
"course7":"NA","course8":"NA","course9":"NA","course10":"NA",
"course11":"NA","course12":"NA","course13":"NA","course14":"NA",
"course15":"NA","course16":"NA","lon":11.97456,"lat":57.70887,
"website1":"http://www.emm-nano.org/",
"website2":"http://ws1.roehampton.ac.uk/admissions/erasmusmundus/hrp/index.html",
"website3":"http://www.mfamily.eu/",
"website4":"NA","website5":"NA","website6":"NA",
"website7":"NA","website8":"NA","website9":"NA",
"website10":"NA","website11":"NA","website12":"NA",
"website13":"NA","website14":"NA","website15":"NA",
"website16":"NA","code":"Gothenburg","title":"Gothenburg"
```

As you can see, the urls which will serve as href are strings within the array.  Each `course` is connected to a `website` so that `course1` should be linked to `website1`, `course2` should be linked to `website2` and so on.  At this point, my popups *only* display courses and links separately for example:

[image]

with the following code to remove the `NA` and other unwanted values:

```
  var feature = features[0];
  function htmlFromProps(props) {
    var html = "";
    var i = 0;
    for (p in props) {
      if (props[p] && props[p] != "null" && props[p] != "NA") {
        html += "<div>" + (i === 0 ? "<strong>" : "");
        html += props[p];
        html += (i++ === 0 ? "</strong>" : "") + "</div>\n";
      }
    }
    return html;
  }

//delete unnecessary elements*
  delete feature.properties["field_1"];
    delete feature.properties["lon"];
      delete feature.properties["lat"];
        delete feature.properties["code"];
        delete feature.properties["title"];
  // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
  // based on the feature found.
  popup.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML(htmlFromProps(feature.properties))
      .addTo(map);

}
```

This works, but the links are not attached to the `course` names. I am interested in only displaying the course names themselves that include `href`s Is there a programmatic way to go about this in JS without using CSS?  I have researched several examples as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370511/java-script-how-to-loop-though-a-list-of-hrefs) but it is not applicable to the structure as it is now.  Any advice on how to go about this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the properties into course and website arrays and then process them to match them up.

The following is an example:

```js
var properties = {
  "city": "Gothenburg",
  "course1": "EMM-Nano",
  "course2": "EMHRPP",
  "course3": "MFAMILY",
  "course4": "NA",
  "course5": "NA",
  "course6": "Course6",
  "course7": "Course7",
  "course8": "Course8",
  "course9": "Course9",
  "course10": "Course10",
  "course11": "Course11",
  "course12": "Course12",
  "course13": "Course13",
  "course14": "Course14",
  "course15": "Course15",
  "course16": "Course16",
  "course17": "Course17",
  "course18": "Course18",
  "course19": "Course19",
  "course20": "Course20",
  "course21": "Course21",
  "website1": "url1",
  "website2": "url2",
  "website3": "url3",
  "website4": "NA",
  "website5": "NA",
  "website6": "url6",
  "website7": "url7",
  "website8": "url8",
  "website9": "url9",
  "website10": "url10",
  "website11": "url11",
  "website12": "url12",
  "website13": "url13",
  "website14": "url14",
  "website15": "url15",
  "website16": "url16",
  "website17": "url17",
  "website18": "url18",
  "website19": "url19",
  "website20": "url20",
  "website21": "url21",
};


alert("Output:" + htmlFromProps(properties));

function htmlFromProps(props) {
  var city = "";
  var courses = [];
  var websites = [];
  for (p in props) {
    if (props[p] && props[p] != "null" && props[p] != "NA") {
      if (isCourse(p)) {
        courses[getIndex(p)] = props[p];
      } else if (isWebsite(p)) {
        websites[getIndex(p)] = props[p];
      } else {
        city = props[p];
      }
    }
  }
  return buildHTML(city, courses, websites);
}

function isCourse(propname) {
  return (propname.indexOf("course") != -1);
}

function isWebsite(propname) {
  return (propname.indexOf("website") != -1);
}

function getIndex(propname) {
  var indexRegEx = new RegExp("^.*?(\\d+)$");
  var matches = indexRegEx.exec(propname);
  if ((matches != null) && (matches.length == 2)) {
    return parseInt(matches[1]);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function buildHTML(city, courses, websites) {
  var html = "";
  html += "<div><strong>";
  html += city;
  html += "</strong></div>\n";

  for (i = 1; i < courses.length; i++) {
    if (courses[i]) {
      html += "<div>";
      html += "<a href='" + websites[i] + "'>" + courses[i] + "</a>";
      html += "</div>\n";
    }
  }
  return html;
}
```

Just ignore the var properties and the alert statements at the top of this snippet and replace the htmlFromProps() function with your original and add all the remaining functions in this snippet below htmlFromProps() to your code.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  Is there a way to put the `:url` into an href?  Would one have to then spilt the new array by `:`  ?

Comment: The href is aded to the buildHTML.  This can be changed in any way needed to generate the required HTML.  The answer has been edited to add the href tag.

Comment: For some reason, the code is not working properly if I have more than 10 different courses and websites.  For example, if I have 15 of courses, it will only show `course11`, `course12`, `course13`, `course14`, and `course15`, but not the first 10.  And if I have 20 courses, it will show `course11` - `course19`and skip `course20` as well as the first ten.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The regex was not correctly parsing the 2 or more digit numbers.  The .* was matching all digits except the last one - so only returning the last digit as a match each time.  The new ? qualifier will only match non digits at the end - leaving all the training digits to match.  Also the buildHTML needed to check for array elements that had not been populated - so the if (cources[i]) was added - otherwise empty courses were output.

Comment: That makes sense.  Could you update the code so that it will take into account 2-digit numbers as well?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried this:  `new RegExp("^(.*?)(\d+)(\D*)$")` but does not work

Comment: I am sorry - I meant to say that I had updated the code snippet.  The regex was updated, the buildHTML was updated and the example data was updated to properly test the changes.  The regex above did not work as the extra sets of () created additional groupings which will interfere with the getIndex logic to retrieve the index.  The \d+ will match one or more so only it is needed to match multiple digits.

Comment: Thanks for that !

Answer (score 0):

```js
var html = getHtml()
console.log(html)
document.write(html)
function getHtml(){
  var links = getLinks(getData())
  return links.map((x)=>{
    return `<a href="${x.website}">${x.course}</a>`
  }).join(",\n")  
}

function getLinks(data){
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((last,x)=>{
    if (/course(\d+)/.test(x)){
      var websiteKey = 'website'+RegExp.$1
      if(data[x] != 'NA' && data[websiteKey] && data[websiteKey]!='NA'){
        last.push({
          course:data[x],
          website:data[websiteKey].replace('http: //','http://')
        })
      }
    }
    return last
  },[])
}

function getData(){
  return {
    "field_1": 71,
    "city": "Gothenburg",
    "course1": "EMM-Nano",
    "course2": "EMHRPP",
    "course3": "MFAMILY",
    "course4": "NA",
    "course5": "NA",
    "course6": "NA",
    "course7": "NA",
    "course8": "NA",
    "course9": "NA",
    "course10": "NA",
    "course11": "NA",
    "course12": "NA",
    "course13": "NA",
    "course14": "NA",
    "course15": "NA",
    "course16": "NA",
    "lon": 11.97456,
    "lat": 57.70887,
    "website1": "http: //www.emm-nano.org/",
    "website2": "http: //ws1.roehampton.ac.uk/admissions/erasmusmundus/hrp/index.html",
    "website3": "http: //www.mfamily.eu/",
    "website4": "NA",
    "website5": "NA",
    "website6": "NA",
    "website7": "NA",
    "website8": "NA",
    "website9": "NA",
    "website10": "NA",
    "website11": "NA",
    "website12": "NA",
    "website13": "NA",
    "website14": "NA",
    "website15": "NA",
    "website16": "NA",
    "code": "Gothenburg",
    "title": "Gothenburg"
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.   How to get rid of the space in between `http:` and `//` ?

Comment: updated, just replace, you can find a way for your own

Comment: Thanks, any idea why I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined` ?

Comment: Maybe I have to reference an external script file?

Comment: getData() means get the Data, case you have your data, replace it, case not you can copy all code in snippet, getData is defined in the last section